# CSP block Google Tag Manager in NextJs still using nonce

Tags: reactjs, next.js, content-security-policy, nonce

I am using google tag manager in my project, but when I add the CSP, it blocks GTM.

CSP:

```
default-src https: http: 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-{NONCE-KEY}' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com;
```

Code:

```
<Html lang='es'>
    <Head nonce='{NONCE-KEY}'>
        <script
            nonce='{NONCE-KEY}'
            aria-hidden='true'
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;var n=d.querySelector('[nonce]');
                n&&j.setAttribute('nonce',n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce'));f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${GTM_ID}');`,
                        }}
        />
    </Head>
    <body aria-label='Cargando'>
        <noscript                  
            aria-hidden='true'
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: `<iframe  src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${GTM_ID}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
                        }}
        />
        <Main />
        <div id='tooltip' />
        <NextScript nonce='{NONCE-KEY}' />
    </body>               
</Html>
```

Error:

[image: Image of CSP block GTM]

According to the documentation adding only nonce should work, as I don't want to add the 'unsafe-eval' directive to my CSP for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is not clear from your error message whether it is caused by GTM or some other script. However `'unsafe-eval'` is required for GTM only when custom JavaScript variable names are used in the "Custom HTML tags".
   To get rid of  `'unsafe-eval'` you can use [custom templates](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates) instead of custom JavaScript variable names.
2. Never use strict Content Security Policy based on the `default-src` directive because it leads to [fatal security consequences in Firefox](https://csplite.com/csp325/#strict_CSP_default-src).

Comment: Thank you very much, the crash message was caused by GTM, since I was using Custom Javascript Variables, I made the change to Data Layer Variables and from my app I sent those values through the push method.
I also improved the policy taking into account to avoid default-src.

Thanks!